# Email HTML: How to keep relative same size on all devices?

Tags: html, css, inline

In HTML, how can I got about creating tables so that no matter what service the viewer is using, the size of the page will be about the same size across all viewing? I know you can use pixels to define size, but on a Retina Macbook that would display much smaller than something with less pixel display right?

I'm mostly concerned with it working across different email providers on the web from a computer for this.

---

```html
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: do you mean absolute size to the world, as in it will ALWAYS look 10cm wide, or absolute size to the device containing it, as in it will ALWAYS cover half the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't* use mm or cm unless you're printing.  It's a really unreliable unit.  No, retina devices (unless the user has chosen otherwise, in which case you shouldn't fix it anyway) scale everything up.  Essentially, you're maintaining the same display port and just increasing pixel density with a retina.  Use `px` and be satisfied.

Comment: yes I checked my comment and found it was wrong. I learn something new every day!

Comment: Okay thats neat, thank you so much, that should solve my worry then!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better using a percentage approach or ems to achieve a more uniformed look across all viewports. Look into [Responsive Web Design](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_responsive_intro.asp) for best results

For example

```
table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: percentage is percentage of the viewport NOT an absolute value

Comment: Maybe I am reading the question incorrectly but it looks to me that he doesn't want something 600px wide regardless of device. For the table to be more consistent 'across all devices', use of percentages could work, even though percentage isn't technically a length unit

Comment: OP says "size of the page will be about the same size across all devices?", and given that devices range from inches to feet in diameter, a percentage of this value would only give relative - rather that absolute - values.

Comment: I have asked OP for more clarification

Comment: I edited it a bit. My goal is to make an email that will display the whole template in the quick look portion of an email service online like gmail, yahoo or outlook

Answer (score 0):

reading up here: https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/ there seems to be nothing that will give a reliable scale length dimension. Best bet would be to use a fixed value such as `px` and then scaling/multiplying that based on the browser pixel density (which would require browser feedback on the page), this only *may* be needed as I don't know as yet if all browsers take pixel density into account.